# JQuery Mobile not recognizing list item nested in span tag

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm currently trying to integrate JQuery Mobile into an XML based web program (Logi Analytics for anyone that cares). The problem is when I try to wrap their reports with JQuery Mobile its breaking because the program force wraps HTML elements are wrapped in span tags.

**Example**

The code I would enter would look like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>Cool list item!</li>
</ul>
```

But the code that would be output would look like this:

```
<span>
  <ul data-role="listview">
    <span>
      <li>Cool list item!</li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Thus breaking the classes that jquery mobile would ultimately put on the related list items. Does anyone know a work around to force JQM to target child list items inside spans or other elements?

Comment: Spans in JQM are mainly for text enhancement. I guess it possible to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [**unwrapping**](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) your li elements, like this:

```
$('ul > span > li').unwrap();
```

Comment: You are amazing. I've been struggling with work arounds on this project for weeks! Thank you so much!